# "Error: File Not Found" in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: java, file, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

So my Ubuntu terminal is claiming that the java file I'm trying to run does not exist. However, it clearly does, and it looks like I'm in the right directory. Here's what I'm trying to compile

[image: Trying to compile this highlighted java file; it looks like I'm in the right directory]

And here's what happens
[image]

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Show us the output of `ls -al`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another comment suggested that I use "ls" to see if the terminal can see the file. I got a permission denied error, and used

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that you are in the right directory, BE SURE that you write the filename Exactly as what it is. Because **Linux is case sensitive** and for example, if you have a file with name "Sample" and you try to open "sample" file, you will get the error.

if you type manually, try to use **Tab button** in your keyboard. it will auto-Complete the file/dir name for you. With this way, if you have typo or wrong spelling, Tab does not complete the name and you will know that there is something wrong with what you type in terminal.