# Getting FileNotFoundException in Ubuntu 18.04 with Java

Tags: java, file, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, filenotfoundexception

Compiling of my java program seems to work okay, but when I try to run it using a file as one of the String[] args, I get a file not found exception. However, the file is present in the directory, and I've triple checked the spellings. Here's what I'm trying to do:
[image]

And here's the directory showing my file clearly in it
[image]

And when I do an ls command on this directory, only my .java and .class files show up. None of the .txt files. Could this have something to do with my problem?
[image]

Can anyone help?

Edit: code of file I'm trying to run

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class cs3421_emul {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String directory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            directory = directory.replace("\\", "\\\\");
            //File file = new File(directory + "/" + args[0]);
            File file = new File(args[0]);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
            StreamHandler stream = new StreamHandler(sc);
            while(sc.hasNext()) {
                String datatype = sc.next();
                switch(datatype) {
                    case("memory"):
                        stream.HandleMemory();
                    break;
                    case("clock"):
                        stream.HandleClock();
                    break;
                    case("cpu"):
                        stream.HandleCPU();
                    break;
                }
            }
            sc.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        } 
        /*
        String size = "0x10000";
        //System.out.println("resolve substring issue " + size.substring(2));
        Memory test = new Memory(size);
        test.reset();
        String[] hexvalues = {"0x0A", "0x0B", "0x2A", "0x2B", "0x11", "0x44", "0x23", "0x93", "0x50", "0x22", "0xAE", "0xDE", "0xAD", "0xBE", "0xEF", "0xFF"};
        test.set("0x1A00", "0x10", hexvalues);
        String[] hexvalues1 = {"0xAE", "0xDE", "0xAD", "0xC0", "0xDE", "0FA", "0xCE", "0xFE", "0xED", "0xCA", "0xFE", "0xBE", "0xEF", "0x30", "0xA8", "0xEE"};
        test.set("0x1A10", "0x10", hexvalues1);
        String[] hexvalues2 = {"0x55", "0xAA", "0x10", "0x20"};
        test.set("0x1A20", "0x04", hexvalues2);
        test.dump("0x1A04", "0x20");
        //String[] testmemory = test.getMemory();
         */
    }

}
```

Comment: *"And when I do an ls command on this directory, only my .java and .class files show up. None of the .txt files. Could this have something to do with my problem?"* that *is* the problem. Are you sure the directory in the screenshot from Windows Explorer (weren't you using Ubuntu?) is the same directory in which you're running the program?

Answer (score 1):

There is something very confusing going on here.

1. Your first screenshot shows that you are running a class whose name is `cs3421_emul`.  I presume that corresponds to the source code.  It shows that you are in a directory whose name is `/home/se/cs3421_emul`.

   Assuming you haven't done something really weird, this directory will be the current directory when you run the command (as per this screenshot).
2. Your second screenshot is a view of a directory described as `LocalState > rootfs > home > se > cs3421_emul`.  That directory listing shows a file called `Sample1_input.txt`.  It does NOT show a file called `cs3421_emul.class` file.
3. Your third screenshot is the output of running `ls` in `/home/se/cs3421_emul`.  It shows the `cs3421_emul.class` file.  It does NOT show a file called `Sample1_input.txt`.

From this, I can only conclude that the directory in your second screenshot is a *different* to the one that is the current directory when you ran `ls` (screenshot three) and when you attempted to run your program using the `java` command (screenshot one).

Now I don't know what that is that you are showing us in the second screenshot.  Is this some view of a Windows file system that is (somehow) being mapped to your Linux?  Or is it a directory that you are copying to the Linux system?

Either way, screenshots one and three are definitive.  They showing the Linux file system from the Linux perspective.  And in that perspective, there is no `Sample1_input.txt` file in the `/home/se/cs3421_emul` directory.  There are no `*.txt` files there at all.

When you run the `java` command like that, on the Linux system, the JVM needs to see a file with the name `Sample1_input.txt` in the `/home/se/cs3421_emul` directory.   If it is not there, that would cause a `FileNotFound` exception with a message is identical to the one you are getting.

You need to figure out why the file `Sample1_input.txt` is not in the `ls` output; i.e. why the file isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

BE SURE that you write the filename Exactly as what it is. Because **Linux is case sensitive** and for example, if you have a file with name "Sample" and you try to open "sample" file, you will get the error.

I think you have the same problem as [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58046484/error-file-not-found-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts/58046670#58046670). check it out

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem. As you can see from the third screenshot the file is actually not in that directory.